# ActiveRecord Grouping posts created by the same user in the past hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Story model. A story is created by a user, and those stories go into a feed. If a user creates more than one story within an hour, I want to only show one story, so my question is how do I write an ActiveRecord query to group by `created_at` to the hour, and `user_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turned out to be pretty easy.

```
Story.find_each.group_by do |story|
  [story.user_id, story.created_at.beginning_of_hour]
end
```

then you can map over the results and do whatever. I checked if a group had more than one object in it, and if it did, created a new Story, inserted the info for all the stories I wanted to group, and then added it to an array of stories. I never save the new story, so I don't end up with a bunch of weird stories saved.

If anyone has a better way to do this, I'm open to suggestions.

Here is the entire method:

```
def self.smart_feed
    feed = []
    self.find_each(batch_size: 10).group_by do |story|
      [story.user_id, story.created_at.beginning_of_hour]
    end.map do |stories|
      if stories.second.count > 1
        temp_story = self.new()
        stories.second.map do |story|
          if story.ratings.any?
            temp_story.ratings.append(story.ratings)
          elsif story.flights.any?
            temp_story.flights.append(story.flights)
          end
          temp_story.description = "Added #{temp_story.ratings.size} new ratings and #{temp_story.flights.size} new flights"
          temp_story.user_id = story.user_id
        end
        feed.append(temp_story)
      else
        feed.append(stories.second.first)
      end
    end
    return feed.reverse
  end
```

Comment: This solution is pretty slow, so happy to hear alternatives. I'll update when I get around to improving it.